# Storing pointers in a vector in a data-read-in function

Tags: c++, pointers, boost

I have a txt file with league, teams and players which looks like this :

```
League: some league

Team:  some team

some players with name and strength

League: some other league
```

Now i read in the data with my readin function

```
#include "ReadIn.h"
#include "Player.h"
#include <deque>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>


std::string zeile,word1, word2, sname, lname;
std::deque<Team*> Teamvector;
int str, a = 0, b = 0 , c = 0;
using namespace std;

void readin_fillVector(std::deque<Team> &v, std::deque<League> & w, std::vector<Player> u) {
    ifstream fin("C:\\Users\\david\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\Anstoss2014\\Datenbank\\test.txt");

    //Einlesen der Zeilen starten
    while (getline(fin, zeile))
    {

        fin >> word1;
        //find out if this line contains the team name or the players
        if (word1 == "Liga:"){
            getline(fin, word2);
            //deleting the empty space in front of the team name
            word2.erase(0, 1);
            w.push_back(League(word2, c));
            c++;
        }
        else if (word1 == "Verein:"){
            getline(fin, word2);
            //deleting the empty space in front of the team name
            word2.erase(0, 1);
            v.push_back(Team(word2, a));

            //League gets the new member ( the team which was read in the line before)
            w.back().AddTeam(&v.back());
            //Team gets an pointer to the league it plays in
            v.back().SetLeague(&w.back());
            a++;
        }
        else{
            fin >> lname >> str;
            Player* player = new Player();
            player->setinformation_(b, word1, lname, str, &v.back());
            u.push_back(*player);
            v.back().AddPlayer(player);
            //for (size_t f = 0; f < v.back().GetPlayerList().size(); f++)
            //{
            //  v.back().GetPlayerList()[f]->getinformation_();
            //}
            b++;

        }
        
    }

}
```

This works out like it should, but i'm confused with the line

```
Player* player = new Player();
```

I read much about pointers and there was said that this player created by new() should be deleted somehow. So first question is :1. Is this right ?

But if i do this in my function, the player's information stored in the team's playervector is lost.

2.I have boost accessable, should i use something like boost::ptr_vector ?

3.If not, what else could i do to avoid memory leak ?

**EDIT**:

Another way i tried this was

```
Player player;
player.setinformation_(b, word1, lname, str, &v.back());
u.push_back(player);
v.back().AddPlayer(&player);
```

But this ended in the the players having no more information stored when the function returns the teamvector. The output is just cryptic then.

Comment: This code wont compile, you cant insert a `Player*` in a `std::vector<Player>` without dereferecning. Simply get rid off all the pointer. You dont need them. And yes you MUST call `delete` (if you dont use the object anymore)

Comment: i do dereference it and it works, everything is okay there my question is all about deleting this pointers. I have no idea how to do it without pointers, wouldn't that be kind of a circular dependence ?

Comment: `Player player; vec.push_back(player);` ?

Comment: That does not work out as i need to create many players in the loop and point to them, the only way i managed to do this is by Player* player = new Player(), your way leads pointers pointing to the wrong adresses

Comment: `std::vector` already manages objects on the heap and is a **dynamic** sized container. As long your vector doesnt run out of scope everything is fine. And btw: It doesnt make ANY difference at all whether you write: `vec.push_back(*ptr);` or `vec.push_back(obj);` in both cases a copy is created.

Comment: I editet my post to show what i already tested, if i understand you right this is the way you suggested me to do it.

Comment: The problem in this case is `v.back().AddPlayer(&player);` changing it to `v.back().AddPlayer(&u.back());` will probably work, but you should really reconsider your design.

Comment: This does lead to acces violation errors, thx for your idead but i really dont know how to desing it in another way that's why i asked ;)

Comment: @jimbo999 Welcome to C++ where user defined have value semantics. Use smart-pointers for anything else. Storing pointers in containers is rarer and most useful for (virtual) polymorphism. Which is already rarer in C++ too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you are passing in your `std::vector<Player>` by value. You probably meant to pass it in by reference otherwise any changes you make to it will be lost.

Regarding your specific question, your 'Another way' looks nearly right but you are storing a pointer to the local `player` variable in your teamvector. When the local `player` goes out of scope this pointer will be left dangling. You need to store a pointer to the copy of player in the player vector because that is what owns the players.

However, as you discovered, even this will not work because when the the player vector is reallocated during a `push_back` all pointers to the elements of the vector will be invalidated. You could `reserve` ahead of time all the space you need in the player vector to ensure no reallocation happens but you might not know how much space to `reserve`. You could use a different STL container like a `std::list` which promises that pointers will not be invalidated. But if you don't want to compromise on your choice of container I suggest you create your player objects on the heap and use smart pointers to manage the memory, either `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`. So the function prototype would look like:

```
in_fillVector(std::deque<Team> &v, std::deque<League> & w, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Player>> &u)
```

And adding the players would look like:

```
auto player = std::unique_ptr<Player>(new Player());
player->setinformation_(b, word1, lname, str, &v.back());
v.back().AddPlayer(player.get());
u.push_back(std::move(player));
```

Comment: The problem remains the same, after returing the vectors the player in the teamvector have no information left

Comment: Okay, i found out the reason, it's because the players are created in a loop so adding new Players will change the memory adress of the one's added earlier. std::deque works, but that is not what i want because i need to delete players from every position of the container

Comment: Ah, @jimbo999, you are right! If the vector is reallocated during a push_back all pointers, references or iterators are invalidated. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329956/do-stl-iterators-guarantee-validity-after-collection-was-changed) and [this](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Vector.html). Looks like I need to edit my answer...

Comment: @jimbo999 removal of elements from the middle of std::vector is linear time just like std::deque. std::list supports constant time removal from the middle but might not be what you want for other reasons.

Comment: i read that you CAN'T delete element from the middle of deque, just from the end or the beginning. Is this right ?

Comment: std::deque::erase can delete elements from the middle of the deque although that WILL invalidate all pointers to the deque.

Comment: Okay thx for your help that clarified a lot to me, will go on i a new question ;)